# sauvegarde de session whit ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I connect with an external link of an API then I have to keep the session to consume another link with the connected session , 
it's the code for authentication, I need to send a new post request to display a list but with the same login session

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ1RV.png)

Comment: pls always add code as text in your question and not as screenshot

Comment: if (this.user && this.pwd)  {
            
let postData=new FormData();
            postData.append('username',this.user);
            postData.append('password',this.pwd);
            this.http.post(this.Urls,postData, {withCredentials: true })
            .subscribe( Response => { console.log(Response.json());
               if (!Response.json().token)    {console.log('connexio non reussi reussi');   this.presentAlerts();          }else {    console.log('connexio   reussi');   this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);   console.log( Response.headers.getAll("set cookie"));  }
            }); }